# Rails create relationship record dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: Image and Lightbox. To relate the two models (has_many) I have a third model LightboxImages.

One Lightbox can have several Images and a Image can be in various Lightboxes.

A Lightbox is created dynamically (with remote js) and the user can add Images to this Lightbox dynamically too.

My first idea was to simply create a url to the create method of the LightboxImages Controller passing the Lightbox Id and Image Id as parameter.

However, this approach seemed fragile and insecure, since a user could easily simulate such behavior.

What is the best design for this situation, create relationship records dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean “since a user could easily simulate such behavior”. If you want the user to be able to do something, then they have to, well, be able to do it.

Comment: Yes, but simple call a url in browser? I know the create method using a POST but sounds me a fragile design, no?

Comment: creating something dynamically would never mean to solve malicious input by itself. If it exists non remote, it will exist remote.

Comment: i think you are confusing 2 things. Having a post url action that creates things is totally normal - the authenticity token should resolve ur security concerns.

Comment: Another point ... For this to work I have to set the url to call in the JavaScript itself, it does not increase the coupling? I'm not confused, I just want to know from more experienced people if this is really the right solution ...

Comment: Using POST is the right way, but even then, your controller should have enough checks to ensure that the user has permissions to do the operation. Lets say if the image belongs_to user, then in your action, find the image like current_user.images.find(params[:image_id]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have a fourth model -- User.   I'm assuming you do anyway.

```
User has_many :lightboxes
Lightbox has_many :lightbox_items
Image has_many :lightbox_items
LightboxItem belongs_to :lightbox
LightboxItem belongs_to :image
Lightbox has_many :images, :through => :lightbox_item
Image has_many :lightboxes, :through => :lightbox_item
```

LightboxItem is where you might want to store additional data like the position of the image in that specific Lightbox.

The key thing is that every Lightbox belongs to a User.  With this you can then scope all of the AR calls in your controller to the current user -- thus preventing them from modifying other light boxes.

So, user carlos has lightbox id 1.  User phallstrom has lightbox id 2.

In your controller, you somehow set `current_user` to the current user in a before filter.  Then, for example in the action to get the specified light box you would do something like this:

```
@lightbox = current_user.lightboxes.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
```

In doing it this way if current_user is carlos, and params[:id] is 2, nothing will be returned.

Similarly, for all the other CRUD actions you'd scope it to current_user as well.

Comment: Yes, I have the User model as well. I understand the issue of security checks. And to add images to a lightbox should I call via js the create method of the controller LightboxImages (making the appropriate checks)?!

Comment: JS or regular is up to you.  As long as the scope on current user is in place it's a personal preference.